# BitBucket Pipelines Persist Data

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker

I would like to persist data within a run of BitBucket Pipelines. A simple case is my first test creates a user record in Mongo and the second one attempts to get that user, however, on Pipelines it always returns that the user record doesn't exist. I understand that I could use a mock repository but I prefer to not go with this route. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: java:8
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      script:
        - bash ./gradlew build
        - bash ./gradlew test
      services:
        - mongo

definitions:
  services:
    mongo:
      image: mongo
```

Comment: my opinion is you should make your test independent on previous tests... maybe you want to use *artifacts* https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/using-artifacts-in-steps-935389074.html

Comment: @MazelTov you're correct. I need to put the create in the same test method. If you make this an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my opinion is you should make your test independent on previous tests...